# How to check whether an internet/network connection available or not , but only for once

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

How Can I check if an internet connection is available or not **but Only For ONCE (One Time)** . **Remember One Time Execution Only**

I am using the following code but it is continuously monitoring the availability of the internet connection. **I want to run it (execute) it only once**. How can I do it or there is a **way to check for a function that it has been executed or not** with the help of boolean type Variable?

I have tried the loop for(i=0 to i = 1) but it  makes my application crash every time.

```
private function init():void
{
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.NETWORK_CHANGE, onNetworkChange);
    monitorConnection();
}

private function onNetworkChange(event:Event):void
{
    trace('network change');
    monitorConnection();
}

private function monitorConnection():void
{
    monitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest(strURLMonitor));
    monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,announceStatus);
    monitor.start();
}

private function announceStatus(e:StatusEvent):void {
    trace("Status change. Current status: " + monitor.available);
    if(monitor.available)
    {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Any Help will be greatly Admired

Thank You
Udit Bhardwaj

Answer (score 3):

Best practice would be to ping some server that's always online - like Google for example :)
It's easy and fast. The URLMonitor is for monitoring, not for test.. And there is no built-in function just for single test.

Use simple URLLoader :)

Comment: strURLMOnitor is a string variable have value www.Google.com So it is continuously monitoring . and i am having an endless loop like situation
private var strURLMonitor   : String = 'http://www.google.com'; 
   private var monitor         : URLMonitor;

Comment: As I said - just use [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) and make a single request to Google.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i used a Global "Boolean Variable" for this with condition "false" and after execution i changed it's value to "True" and if(IsExecuted == false){further Execution} else{no execution}
Thanks A lot for the answer

Answer (score -1):

Just do...  "monitor.removeEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,announceStatus);" and call only once monitorConnection();

```
private function monitorConnection():void
{
    monitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest(strURLMonitor));
    monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,announceStatus);
    monitor.start();
}

private function announceStatus(e:StatusEvent):void {
    monitor.removeEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS,announceStatus);
    trace("Status change. Current status: " + monitor.available);
    if(monitor.available)
    {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if that's the case, at least use `stop` instead of just removing the listener - this means that it will continue to work but you won't get listeners.. Which means totally not needed memory leak!